# One array in another

Tags: c, arrays, unions

I have a union:

```
typedef union element{
    int number;
    char letter;
} Element; // used typedef for faster writing of code
```

I then went ahead and created an array of unions, limited to 10 unions. Therefore, I have:

```
Element set[10];
```

As such, I can input 10 alphanumerical values in the array.

I would now like to create an array of set[10]. Let's call this array aOfSets.

Typing the following produced an error, and I'm not sure how to create such array:

```
set[10] * aOfSets;
```

I'd like to allocate more space as the program progresses, so I want aOfSets to be a pointer in order to use malloc(), i.e. I'd like to do something like:

```
aOfSets = malloc(1 * (set));
aOfSets = realloc(aOfSets, 2 * (set));
```

Really, my only problem is that I don't know how the array aOfSets can be made into an array of arrays (set[10]).

Is this even possible? Help appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already you probably forgot the `typedef`

```
typedef Element set[10];
```

Then a pointer to array is simply

```
set *aOfSets;
```

If you don't want to go through the `typedef` use

```
Element (*aOfSets)[10];
```

which is equivalent.